# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/Request$Body in feign while adding support for multipart/form-data

Tags: multipartform-data, noclassdeffounderror, feign

I am trying to proxy multipart request via feign.

```
@PostMapping(value = "{pathUri1}/{pathUri2}",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<?>> uploadFileCall(@PathVariable(value = "pathUri1") String pathUri1, @PathVariable(value = "pathUri2") String pathUri2, @RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam Map<Object,Object> requestParam, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders);
```

this is service call.

```
@Configuration
class MultipartSupportConfig {

    @Autowired
    ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
    }
}
```

added encoder config for multipart/form-data .

I have followed this 
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form

But I am getting `hystrixRunTimeException` which is caused because of 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/Request$Body error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use feign-form-spring 3.4.1 version.

Gradle

```
compile(group: 'io.github.openfeign.form', name: 'feign-form-spring', version: '3.4.1')
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-form</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Check requirements https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form#requirements

Comment: I addded one more dependency along with it - feign-form-spring

Answer (score 2):

According to the [open-feign's github document](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form), Please **Note** the feign-form's versions:

- all feign-form releases before 3.5.0 works with OpenFeign 9.* versions;
- starting from feign-form's version 3.5.0, the module works with OpenFeign 10.1.0 versions and greater.

Answer (score 0):

The following config works for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where:

<feign.version>11.0</feign.version>

<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>